# Select Object(rectangle, circle, Images etc.) In my 2d canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question.

I drawn my object like rectangles, circles, images etc.

```
if (element.type === "rectangle"){
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.strokeRect(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
} else if (element.type === "circle") { //draw circle 1
  ctx.moveTo(x1, y1 + (y2 - y1) / 2);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x1, y1, x2, y1, x2, y1 + (y2 - y1) / 2);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x2, y2, x1, y2, x1, y1 + (y2 - y1) / 2);
  ctx.closePath();
} else {
     ctx.drawImage(image, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
}
```

Anyway, the figures are well drawn.

When I click, I want to know the information of the shape.
for rotation, move, resize...

how can I get the information?
thank you...

[image: my canvas]

Comment: Vanilla canvas API does not give you that ability. Either you need to do it yourself (listen to `click` event and locate corresponding object according to coordinate) or use some third party library.

Comment: I did not use vanilla canvas . just pure html, javascript.
do you have some example? thank you

Comment: In pure (also known as "vanilla") canvas API, there's no "object" or "element". If you want to manipulate shapes/images/etc as objects, you need to use [some canvas library](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=javascript%20canvas%20library&addon=opensearch).